# Is there a hex calculator in UltraEdit?

Tags: ultraedit

Is there a hex/binary calculator in UltraEdit? For instance, to find the decimal value for hex value `493E`.

I can't seem to find it in the menus (files can be edited in binary mode, but I simply want to convert to and from decimal and hex values).

Comment: You mean a hex to decimal converter.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a hex calculator, but it is well hidden. It is in the context menu (right-click or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>). In order to start it:

1. Select a number in an existing document (or type some number in a new document and select it).
2. Start menu command "Number Converter".

If the selection is empty or some letters are selected, nothing will happen when the menu command is started.

[image: Screenshot of starting up the hex calculator in UltraEdit]

This was tested in UltraEdit v. 16.2.